# Can you break out of filter function when certain condition is met? For example I want to break the filter function if x == 237

Tags: python, filter, lambda

```
numbers = [
386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
958,743, 527]

print(list(filter(lambda x: (x%2 == 0 or x == 237) , numbers)))
print(list(filter(lambda x: x if x%2 == 0 else x == 237 , numbers)))
```

Comment: Maybe you could use [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) instead.

Comment: You don't need ```lambda``` for that. ```new_l=[x for x in numbers if x%2==0 or x==237]```

Comment: There is [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Sujay: Using a list comprehension isn't the same think a breaking out of the loop — assuming that's what the OP means by "break out of filter function".

Comment: @codingworld: What exactly do you mean by "break out of filter function"?

Comment: for x in numbers: # not looking to use for loop 
    if x == 237:
        print(x)
        break;
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)

Comment: In that case, no you can't break out if you're using the built-in `filter()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can write you own implementation based on [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) as suggested in the comments

```
def take_while(predicate, stop_condition, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        if x == stop_condition:
            break

print(list(take_while(lambda x: x % 2 == 0 or x == 237, 237, numbers)))
print(list(take_while(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else x == 237, 237, numbers)))
```

Output

```
[386, 462, 418, 344, 236, 566, 978, 328, 162, 758, 918, 237]
[386, 462, 418, 344, 236, 566, 978, 328, 162, 758, 918, 237]
```

Another option will be to slice the list based on the index of the number

```
stop_index = numbers.index(237) + 1 if 237 in numbers else len(numbers)
# stop_index = numbers.index(237) + 1
print(list(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0 or x == 237), numbers[:stop_index])))
print(list(filter(lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else x == 237, numbers[:stop_index])))
```